# SwiftUI - why does contentShape block clicking on an overlay?

Tags: macos, swiftui

This is some boiled down code from a real app. I tried to use an offset overlay to create a little popup that sits next to an item in a list. I discovered that `contentShape()` would interfere with `tapGesture` on the overlay. If I uncomment the `.contentShape(Rectangle())` line in the following example, you can no longer click on the blue overlay.

Anyone understand why? Maybe it's a bug. I'm running this on macOS 11.2.3.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            OverlayTapTest()
                // .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .zIndex(1)
            Text("Line 2")
            Text("Line 3")
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}


struct OverlayTapTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("OverlayTapTest - Test")
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture { print("Tapped Text") }
            .overlay(
                Text("OverlayTapTest - Overlay")
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture { print("Tapped Overlay") }
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .offset(x: 20, y: 18),
                alignment:.topLeading
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You used **onTapGesture** in wrong order, see the working way:

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            OverlayTapTest()
                 .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .zIndex(1)
            Text("Line 2")
            Text("Line 3")
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}


struct OverlayTapTest: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("OverlayTapTest - Test")
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .overlay(Text("OverlayTapTest - Overlay")
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture { print("Tapped Overlay") }
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .offset(x: 20, y: 18),
                alignment:.topLeading)
            .onTapGesture { print("Tapped Text") }   // <<: Here
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. I click on the blue rectangle and get nothing. Then if I uncomment the `contentShape()` (the one in `ContentView.body`), I can click on the blue. That's the same behavior as my example.

Comment: My Answer works for me, I am using Xcode: Version 12.4 (12D4e), macOS 11.2.3 (20D91)

Comment: When you click on the blue box, do you see "Tapped Overlay" print in the console?

Comment: yes with my answer, not with your code in question.

Comment: Wow, that's weird. We have the same versions of macOS and Xcode and I'm getting different behavior. I may try a system restart, but ??.